# capacitance to voltage conversion

Tags: capacitance

I need a circuit to convert variable capacitance value to considerable variable DC voltage.

Capacitance value range = 0pF ~ 20pF
DC value range needed = 0V ~ 6V

Please explain in detail as i am newbie.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean like a frequency-to-voltage converter?

Comment: capacitance to voltage converter

Comment: Which is implemented as a frequency-to-voltage converter.

Comment: I made a circuit using 555 generating 1.3KHz PWM with 96% duty cycle and fed that output to the capacitance under test  and then amplified using opamp.DC voltage is varied from 0.5V to 12V for value of capacitance 1nF-15nF.

Comment: now i need DC voltage change of 0-6V for 0pF-20pF.

Comment: One approach for this capacitance range is an AC bridge with a demodulator. Really depends on requirements.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number possible approaches.

Use the fact that impedance at a fixed frequency varies inversely with capacitance.  You basically make a resistance meter, but with AC.  You put in a signal at known voltage and frequency, then measure the voltage of what you get out.

Use the fact that a capacitor together with a inductor define a frequency.  Use the capacitor under test with a known inductor as the frequency-setting part of a oscillator, then measure the frequency.

Dump a fixed charge on the cap and measure voltage.

Charge the cap to a fixed voltage, then discharge thru a known resistor and measure how long it takes to get to a known point on the discharge curve, like 2/3 discharged for example.

Use a known capacitor to see how the two share voltage after being connected with one charged and the other discharged.

Set up a camera with a machine vision system feeding optical character recognition and read the label on the cap.

Use your own brain and get creative.

Comment: Please elaborate on 3 and 4